# how to use character arrays in strcmp() functions

Tags: c, arrays, character

I initialized a character array with a size of four
When I input any character to the character array as

```
char a[4];
a[1]='z';
printf("The character array is %s\n", a);
```

The output shows me

The character array is

But then I change a little bit

```
char a[4];
a[1]='z';
printf("The first character of the array is %s\n", a[1]);
```

The output shows me

The first character of the array is z

Why is that ? How can I use my character arrays such as if I want them to be compared using strcmp() functions.
Please help me....

Comment: Zero-based indexing vs one-based, and a whole lot of undefined behavior on the first call (non-terminated string, indeterminate content in `a[0]`, etc). It would seem you need to flip to the part of your reference describing how nullchar-terminated strings, and the various standard library functions that use them, work

Comment: If you change the code in the question, you should also re-run it and change the output.

Comment: Please, please do not change the question. Rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

In the first piece of code, you only set one element of the array.  The other three elements are uninitialized.  So when you call `printf` and pass in `a` it reads those uninitialized bytes.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as nothing being printed.

What probably happened in this particular case is that the first element of the array, i.e. the one with index 0, was probably 0.  This value is used to terminate strings, so `a` was viewed as an empty string.

Also:

> The first character of the array is z

No it is not.  Arrays in C start with index 0, not index 1.

If you want to copy a string into an array, use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(a, "z");
```

Comment: Sorry I meant the same, in the original code I did write a[0]='z';

Comment: Or (before the question was changed) `char a[4] = "z";`

Comment: what if I want to add a character variable to a preferred address of the array ?

Comment: @user8590061 You mean if you want to set a particular element of the array?  Then you set that element as you did.  But you have to start with a valid string, i.e. an **null terminated** array of characters.

Comment: @user8590061 then please ask another question showing what you tried. You are treating this site as a change-by-change question-and-answer site, but that is not how we work. You asked one question, you got a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this code snippet

```
char a[4];
a[0]='z';
a[1]='y';
printf("The character array is %s\n", a);
```

the array does not contain a string (a sequence of characters terminated with a zero character). However you are trying to output it as a string using the conversion specifier `%s`.

Instead you should write

```
printf("The character array is %*.*s\n", 2, 2, a);
```

In this code snippet

```
char a[4];
a[0]='z';
a[1]='y';
printf("The first character of the array is %c\n", a[0]);
printf("The second character of the array is %c\n", a[1]);
```

again the array does not contain a string. However you are outputting separate characters. So there is no problem.

If you want to store a string in the array you should append it with zero character. For example

```
char a[4];
a[0]='z';
a[1]='y';
a[2] = '\0';
printf("The character array is %s\n", a);
```

The standard C string function `strcmp` deals with strings. So arrays that you are going to use with this function shall contain strings.

Otherewise you can use another standard function `memcmp`.